# markitup - auto detect line breaks

Tags: jquery, parsing, text-editor, line-breaks, markitup

I'm using markitup (markitup.jaysalvat.com) to create a customized editor for users who have no experience with html. I've just included the tags `h1`, `bold` and `hyperlink`.
Now I've a problem with the line break. I've changed the following setting in file *set.js*:

```
onTabEnter: {keepDefault:false, replaceWith:'<br />\n'},
```

to

```
onEnter: {keepDefault:false, replaceWith:'<br/>\n'},
```

Of course it works. Now there's  a `<br/>`-Tag for each klick on Enter/Return. But: 
People write there texts and stories offline in editors like MS Word, Libre Office or simple RTF-Editors. If they want to transfer the saved texts from the offline Editors (using "copy&paste") to markitup the line breaks are lost.

Is there a solution for automatic detect line breaks `\r` or `\n`?
I think there's a difference between Linux and Windows. If it's important: The Webserver is running Linux.

EDIT:
Now i've seen that the line breaks become auto detected when using the BB-Code-Parser of markitup. But I need it with the HTML-Parser.